# How is $\sec{x} +\tan{x} =\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{x}{2}\right) $

Tags: trigonometry

How can you manipulate  $$ \sec{x} + \tan{x}  $$ to get 
$$ \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Write both sides in terms of $\sin\frac x2$ and $\cos\frac x2$ and see if it works.

Comment: Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sec x+\tan x = \frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2+x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac\pi2+x\right)}=\frac{2\sin^2\left(\frac\pi4+\frac x2\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac\pi4+\frac x2\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi4+\frac x2\right)}=\tan\left(\frac\pi4+\frac x2\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sec x+\tan x=\dfrac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}=\dfrac{(\cos x/2+\sin x/2)^2}{\cos^2x/2-\sin^2x/2}$$

Divide numerator and denominator by $\cos x/2+\sin x/2$ assuming that is non zero

Or

$$\sec x+\tan x=\cdots =\dfrac{1-\cos(\pi/2+x)}{\sin(\pi/2+x)}$$

Now use $$\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y,\sin2y=2\sin y\cos y$$